# Confidence Intervals for Standardized Multiple Regression Coefficients

Tags: multiple-regression

For least squares, multiple regression with standardised (i.e. X-E(X)/VAR(X) ) scores, standard statistical packages (e.g. SPSS, R) will produce a confidence interval for each regression coefficient using the standard error +- t-values for given df and CI.

However, this can lead to the case where the confidence interval for a standardised regression coefficient goes above 1 or below -1.

Test Dataset

```
df2=as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(1,3,6,3,5))) #Test Data Frame
df2s=as.data.frame(apply(df2,2,scale)) #Standarise SCores
fit2=lm(V1 ~ V2, data=df2s) #Fit MR
```

Output from multiple regression

```
>summary(fit2) ; confint(fit2) # MR output
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -6.444e-17  3.929e-01   0.000    1.000
V2           6.489e-01  4.393e-01   1.477    0.236

Residual standard error: 0.8786 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4211,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2281 
F-statistic: 2.182 on 1 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.2362

     2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept) -1.2504461 1.250446
V2          -0.7491556 2.046927
>
```

Output from Pearson Correlation

```
    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  df2$V1 and df2$V2
t = 1.4771, df = 3, p-value = 0.2362
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5459072  0.9737118
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.6488857 
>r=0.6488857 ; n = 5; ((1-r^2)/(n-2))^.5 #Manually calculate SE for pearson
[1] 0.4392977
```

The pearson confidence intervals seem more appropriate. I am aware R would calculate the CI using Fisher's Z transformation - is such a solution also fine to use in the case of analysing standardised multiple regression coefficients? In the case of comparing standardised regression coefficients for meta-analysis, would one also use a Fisher's Z transformation?

Comment: Why do you see it as a problem if the absolute values of your coefficients exceed unity?

Comment: Isn't it impossible for standardised coefficients to go above unity?

Comment: If the standardised coefficients cannot above unity, but the confidence intervals can, it suggests something isn't quite right?

Comment: There is no inherent bound on the size standardized coefficients.  To get standardized coefficients and confidence intervals on them, just standardize the data before calculating the regression